# Bad request, zero length response: where is the WCF log, where to investigate?

Tags: .net, wcf, self-hosting

I have a WCF self hosted service, which is called by an AJAX JavaScript.
In some cases the response is Bad Request and the response length is 0.

What I've done so far:

- Inspecting req/resp with fiddler: Request seems to be OK, and response is http 400 'Bad Request' length is 0, so no info, no stack trace etc.
- Trying to set breakpoint in my service implementation: The service method does not even called
- Trying to set all exceptions in VS menu Debug/Exceptions: No exceptions fired.
- Now how to investigate toward?
- Is there any log what self hosted service is writing?
- Any other idea?

Comment: Perhaps network related since the service don't get called?
Host it in IIS/WAS enable monitoring and see if you can reproduce the bug?

Comment: Sorry for not exact specifiaction: I've got a http 400 'Bad Request' which is 0 length, so no error info no statck trace in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable WCF tracing to track that error down. Just add the following snippet to your application configuration file:

```
<configuration>

  <system.diagnostics>

    <sources>

      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>

    </sources>

  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

This will create a log file containing additional information for every request. You can open the log file with the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms732023%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) which provides a nice GUI.

Comment: Thx for answer. I thought there will be / should be something similar log as IIS log would be. Anyway thx

Comment: I did not try because I find out what is the error before... (request max size was exceeded... :-(